# How to get a map array in Javascript to print in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to print a map array into a dropdown on html, I've got the map code as follows:

```
var myMap = new Map(),
    select = document.getElementById('students');

myMap.set("Zane", 45);
myMap.set("Jane", 50);
myMap.set("Rumi", 100);
myMap.set("Ken", 70);
myMap.set("Jake", 37)
```

Now i need to print it into a drop down list and im not sure how,

My html has 
    `< select id="names"> < / select>`

But how do i fill it as a for loop like

```
for (name in myMap) {
  select.add(new Option(myMap[name]));
};
```

Did not do it yet works for a normal array

Comment: why do you use a `Map` isntead of a simpla array structure?

Comment: I wanted to later on use the map in the same context to do math on the numbers (grades)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) to iterate and then template literals to create the option

```js
var myMap = new Map(),
  select = document.getElementById('students');
myMap.set("Zane", 45);
myMap.set("Jane", 50);
myMap.set("Rumi", 100);
myMap.set("Ken", 70);
myMap.set("Jake", 37);

let str = '';
myMap.forEach((key, val) => {
  str += `<option value='${key}'>${val}</option>`

});
select.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<select id='students'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop or you could use [`Map.prototype​.for​Each()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) to loop through the `Map`

```js
var myMap = new Map(),
    select = document.getElementById('names');

myMap.set("Zane", 45);
myMap.set("Jane", 50);
myMap.set("Rumi", 100);
myMap.set("Ken", 70);
myMap.set("Jake", 37)

myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
  select.add(new Option(key, value) )
})

/*
// This also works
for (let entry of myMap) {
  select.add(new Option(entry[0], entry[1]) )
};
*/
```

```html
<select id="names"> </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myMap.entries()` to get the `[key, value]` array and use that to create the dropdown:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('students');
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("Zane", 45);
myMap.set("Jane", 50);
myMap.set("Rumi", 100);
myMap.set("Ken", 70);
myMap.set("Jake", 37);
var html = '';
for (const entry of myMap.entries()) {
  html += '<option value="' + entry[1] + '">' + entry[0] + '</option>';
}
select.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select id="students"></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

As was pointed out in the comments, a Map is possibly not the correct data structure for this. You might be better off using an array.

Nonetheless, you can iterate over a Map using `forEach(...)`:

```
myMap.forEach((key, value) => {
  select.add(new Option(value, key));
});
```

Would give you:

```
<select id="students">
  <option value="45">Zane</option>
  <option value="50">Jane</option>
  <option value="100">Rumi</option>
  <option value="70">Ken</option>
  <option value="37">Jake</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will generate `<option value="Zane">45</option>` etc

Comment: Oh yeah. I'll update the answer. Did I get downvoted for that?

Comment: don't know tbh.